# Fusion layer map - icons not displaying on android 5.0 device (but fine in chrome)

Tags: android, html, google-fusion-tables

Do fusion table layers display on android devices?

As per this link http://lumlei.blogspot.com/2015/06/waste-map-with-selector-base-map-not.html a fusion table layered map display map icons and base map names correctly. But when blog site viewed on android device (5.0) the base map fails to display town names.

Here's html code (with debugged code from by Dr Molle) from my blog site:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#map-canvas img{
padding: 0;
background: transparent;
border: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
#map-canvas { width:500px; height:400px; }
.layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };
</style>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var layer_0;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.15533458599919, 106.11318745800781),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "col1",
      from: "1ah3uh2UaH-z4PCVJ4gJr3nww3qBg3oBFd_ZeB0VD"
    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });
  }
  function changeMap_0() {
  var whereClause;
  var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  if (searchString != '--Select--') {
    whereClause = "'Treatment' = '" + searchString + "'";
  }
  layer_0.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: "col1",
      from: "1ah3uh2UaH-z4PCVJ4gJr3nww3qBg3oBFd_ZeB0VD",
      where: whereClause
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas">
 </div>
 <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <label class="layer-wizard-search-label">
    Edit map view here &gt;
    <select id="search-string_0" onchange="changeMap_0(this.value);">
      <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
      <option value="Active">Active</option>
      <option value="Building">Building</option>
      <option value="None">None</option>
    </select>
  </label> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: On android device I now note a link within Blogger Mobile "view in full website". When this is clicked map displays correctly. So no real problem in hindsight. Thanks John